# The managed metadata menu on left-hand side of the wiki enterprise site lead to a dead end

Tags: managed-metadata, enterprise-wiki, metadata-navigation

I have followed all the steps to activate a managed metadata menu on the wiki enterprise site I created as per indicated by Microsoft: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-a8ddfcd1-a486-4e0f-b1b1-f10ca79fa9bc

But the menu based on the metadata as shown here: 
[image]

leads to a nonexistent page when clicked: 
[image]

It goes to a page that has a friendly URL: mydomain.sharepoint.com/subsite/wikicategory , leading to a page that doesn't exist.

Help! I'd prefer to not have to set up all the navigation manually if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it! For the managed metadata to integrate with friendly URLs, you need to set up a publishing catalogue as per the article below:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-and-disconnect-a-publishing-site-to-a-catalog-in-SharePoint-df2bdea4-ceb0-459a-91d2-a47a1d807d71?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

That's theoretically, I haven't tried it yet, but I think that's the missing link (ha ha)!